# Show values in another tag using values in dropdown - firebase-database

Tags: html, angularjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to generate the System value (child node) using the Equipment (parent node) through drop-down option. So when I select any value of equipment from dropdown it should change the value of the system as well depending on the equipment selected. The JSON file from my Firebase is included below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="equipList">
    <label for="selectequ">Select Equipment</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectequ" data-ng-model="equipment">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display: none">Select Equipment</option>
        <option data-ng-repeat="eq in add track by $index">{{eq.$id}}</option>
    </select>
    <p data-ng-model="system"></p>
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "7889" : {
    "description" : "789",
    "group" : "Mechanical",
    "system" : "789"
  },
  "asd" : {
    "description" : "asd",
    "group" : "Mechanical",
    "system" : "asdf"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="equipList">
    <label for="selectequ">Select Equipment</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectequ" data-ng-model="equipment">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display: none">Select Equipment</option>
        <option data-ng-repeat="eq in add track by $index" value="$index">{{eqData.description}}</option>
    </select>
    <p data-ng-model="add[equipment].system"></p>
</div>
```

Edit: Set the `option` value to be $index. Use the `select` **equipment** value as an index into **add** and retrieve the **system** value

Comment: 'equipment.system' is not printing out the system when I select the equipment

Comment: Sorry, got the Angular version mixed up. See the edit.

Comment: I made some changes to value="{{eqName}}". After that, this value only gets the index such as 0 or 1. But it is displaying the system as well as passing the index instead of the equipment name. How do I get to pass the value ($id) rather than the index?

Comment: eqName should show values "7889", "asd", etc. I've updated `{{eq.$id}}` to `{{eqName}}`.

Comment: I have updated the question by inserting an image of the data that i am retrieving from my firebase-database. As you can see it has the index values, however when i write eqData.$id it shows the equipment value but the eqName is generating the index value!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154677/discussion-between-aliaa-syamimi-and-camden-kid).